# Python3.5 How to convert list of strings to int so I can sum up the total?

Tags: string, list, int, python-3.5

```
import re
numlist = list()
*total = 0*
handle = open('test.txt')
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
    *for nums in x:
        numlist.append(nums)
        value = int(nums)
        total = total+value
```

print(total)*

example of test.txt file:

jhjkhjhhjkhjh 5678 kjhlkjsd lkjaksd  6578 8765 hnhdtriusnfasdasdweefgdf  dfdf dfdfdfdferse5667 9876gjshdi ksdhsks k6453jjhkkk 9087jjskldnjck kjshhdck 9877
khhgjnh 8532 jnhyg 7634iutr jhgpiunegjd 
wert 1234 kjhg 4567 kjh b 0987 jhggebndueh  nhergsus df  9987 7654 0129kk jhikhhhgkjhhjiiksyehf 9876 ijh kjhgj 1234

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get all numbers and sum them your code works if you remove the asterisks and indent it properly. Indentation is crucial in python. And not sure why the asterisks are there?

```
import re

numlist = list()
total = 0
handle = open('test.txt')
for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
    if len(x) > 0:
        for nums in x:
            numlist.append(nums)
            value = int(nums)
            total = total+value
print(total)
```

I would change it a little, and you don't mention what you want to use numlist for so I removed it in the following code.

```
import re

total = 0
with open('test.txt') as handle:
    for line in handle:
        x = re.findall('([0-9]+)', line)
        for num in x:
            total += int(num)
print(total)
```